# SQLite3 no such collation sequence: UNICODE_en-US_LINGUISTIC_IGNORECASE

Tags: database, sqlite3-python

```
con = sqlite3.connect(path)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from Table1')
```

In this Python code, I get an error like

> collation sequence: UNICODE_en-US_LINGUISTIC_IGNORECASE

How can I get data from this Table1?